# I tried to make a calculator but everytime i try subtraction it still makes addition

Tags: python

I tried to make a basic calculator by myself.  I am complately new and that is why ı don't really know where did ı made the mistake. I can make an addition but still when ı try to make subtraction ıt makes addition again. It ıs my first project and ı need help. I am waiting for your responds :)

```
mathematical_operation=input("Choose your mathematical operation ")
print(mathematical_operation)


def addition(str):
    "addition"
    print(str)
    return

if mathematical_operation:= 'addition':

    first=input("first: ")
    print("first")
    second=input("second: ")
    print("second")
    sum=float(first) + float(second)
    print("sum" +str(sum))

def subtraction(str):
        "subtraction"
        print(str)
        return

if mathematical_operation:='subtraction':
    first=input("first: ")
    print("first")
    second=input("second: ")
    print("second")
    dif=float(first) -float(second)
    print("Sum" +str(dif))
```

Comment: You really need to start with an introductory Python reference book, you cannot just guess at syntax to learn properly. You have string literals like `"addition"` that do nothing, you are shadowing built-in `str` and `sum`, you are using the wrong operator `:=` instead of `==`, you have `return` statements that are not useful, and your indentation is inconsistent and invalid.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you used `:=` (walrus) instead of `==` operator.

When you want to compare values, use `==` so replace all your:

```py
if mathematical_operation:='subtraction':
```

by:

```py
if mathematical_operation == 'subtraction':
```

(same goes for "addition")

Comment: You should then click on the "solve" button or "delete the question" button

Comment: Also bear in mind that writing something like `"addition"` inside a python function is of no effect. It will not technically break your code but is incompatible with any sort of best practice. If you want to make a comment inside a function you should use the pythonic syntax `# addition`.

Comment: @andrea thanks for the tip ı'll use it in my next project I am just entery level so basicly ı have no experience

Answer (score -1):

you need to change input types to integers for calculation.

```
first=int(input("first: ")) # converting str to int
print("first")
second=int(input("second: ")) # converting str to int
print("second")
sum=float(first) + float(second)
print("sum" +str(sum))
```

Comment: Hi, this is not correct. When doing the sum (second last line of your code) you are converting the input string to float, which is enough. It makes no sense to convert a string to integer and then convert it to a float later, you just lose information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).